# Getting Server Seed

Tags: php, server, sha256

I have my friends website which has some online gaming system. And this game has something called server seed. Actually it will be in sha256 mode and i tried to get that hash value, but failed on it. It will be hidden on the present day of running game and will be revealed on the next day. Is there any way to get that server seed (probably the hash value or the original string). Thanks so much for helping me from this.b

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to reverse engineer SHA-256 ... which is impossible. I'm assuming this is for CSGO gambling websites or something so the only way you could know what the hash value of today's server seed is by knowing what the input is.